# Html , textbox inside a TR behaving differently in IE vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, user-interface

Textbox input type HTML in (c# aspx) , in Chrome , the value in value= field is printed in the textbox , while In IE , the value needs to be specified again. 
For example ,

```
 <td class="ssFont border5Color">
    <input type=text name="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,       "MENU_CODE")%>"
    value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>" readonly>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%></td>
```

In IE , the textbox has only one entry , while its twice in Chrome. I couldn't find such issue anywhere . has DataBinder got any role in this?

Comment: Am confused. what is changing cross browser

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594/html-differences-between-browsers